# Changing class of elements

Tags: javascript, css, getelementbyid, getelementsbyclassname

I want to set up floating elements in a way it would depend of their amount.

```
<div id="whatever">
   <div class="iwantthischangedto3elements">
      <a href="#">element 1</a>
      <a href="#">element 2</a>
      <a href="#">element 3</a>
   </div>
   <div class="iwantthischangedto2elements">
      <a href="#">element 1</a>
      <a href="#">element 2</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

I can't really figure how to do this.
I'm guessing javascript is the answer, but can't get it work :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function f() {
  var list = document.getElementById("whatever");
  var nbofelements = whatever.getElementsByTagName("a").length;
  return nbofelements ; 
  whatever.getElementsByTagName("div").className += "elements + nbofelements";      
}
</script>
```

Thanks for helping, I really struggle with javascript...

**Edit:** 
Thanks all for your answers.
Sorry i didn't make myself clear enough, english isn't my first language.

Tambo did get what I meant, code works great.

However there's something I forgot... 
An "h1" can be sometimes placed before the "a" list, and should not be counted as an element. Possibly other "h2", "h3", and so on... I want to count only "a" elements...

```
     <div id="whatever">
       <div class="iwantthischangedto3elements">
          <h1>Do no not count this</h1>
          <a href="#">element 1</a>
          <a href="#">element 2</a>
          <a href="#">element 3</a>
       </div>
```

Any idea how to proceed ?
Cheers
Vincent

Comment: The last line of your function will NEVER be executed, because you're returning a value first, therefore the last line will just be skipped.

Comment: Always try giving  meaningful names to an Identifier variables ..

Comment: What are you trying to do? you want to add classes or what?

Comment: *"...in a way it would depend of their amount."* What does that mean?

Comment: So, you want to change the class `iwantthischangedto3elements` to `elements3`? and the second one to `elements2`? Is that correct? Do you want to actually replace the classes? Or append new classes?

Comment: move `return nbofelements ; ` down so that it is the last line in that function.

Comment: look up querySelectorAll, iterating a set using a for loop, string concatenation, the window.onload event, and you should be set.

Comment: [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k1kjf8qd/1/) will dynamically give your elements the class corresponding to the number of children of that div. For your first div it gives all elements a `class="3"` and your second div `class="2"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [for loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) and [Element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList) to add class

```js
var whateverChild = document.querySelectorAll("#whatever div");

for(var i = 0; i < whateverChild.length; i++) {
  //var anchor = document.querySelectorAll(whateverChild);
  if(whateverChild[i].childElementCount == 2){
    whateverChild[i].classList.add("two")
  }else if(whateverChild[i].childElementCount == 3){
    whateverChild[i].classList.add("three")
  }
}
```

```css
.two a{color: green}
.three a{color: red}
```

```html
<div id="whatever">
   <div class="iwantthischangedto3elements">
      <a href="#">element 1</a>
      <a href="#">element 2</a>
      <a href="#">element 3</a>
   </div>
   <div class="iwantthischangedto2elements">
      <a href="#">element 1</a>
      <a href="#">element 2</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

If you have a paragraph in it you can use this

```js
var whateverChild = document.querySelectorAll("#whatever div");

for(var i = 0; i < whateverChild.length; i++) {
 var anchorLength = whateverChild[i].querySelectorAll("a").length;
 if(anchorLength == 2){
    whateverChild[i].classList.add("two")
  }else if(anchorLength == 3){
    whateverChild[i].classList.add("three")
  }
  
}
```

```css
.two a{color: green}
.three a{color: red}
```

```html
<div id="whatever">
   <div class="iwantthischangedto3elements">
      <a href="#">element 1</a>
      <p> i am a paragraph </p>
      <a href="#">element 2</a>
      <a href="#">element 3</a>
   </div>
   <div class="iwantthischangedto2elements">
      <a href="#">element 1</a>
      <a href="#">element 2</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

You can reduce the code to this

```js
var numbersArray  = ["zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five"],
    whateverChild = document.querySelectorAll("#whatever div");

for(var i = 0; i < whateverChild.length; i++) {
 var anchorLength = whateverChild[i].querySelectorAll("a").length;
  
    whateverChild[i].classList.add(numbersArray[anchorLength])
  
}
```

```css
.zero{color: orange}
.one{color: blue}
.two a{color: green}
.three a{color: red}
.four{color: purple}
.five{color: beige;}
```

```html
<div id="whatever">
   <div class="iwantthischangedto3elements">
      <a href="#">element 1</a>
      <p> i am a paragraph </p>
      <a href="#">element 2</a>
      <a href="#">element 3</a>
   </div>
   <div class="iwantthischangedto2elements">
      <a href="#">element 1</a>
      <a href="#">element 2</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks all for your answers.
Sorry i didn't make myself clear enough, english isn't my first language. Tambo did get what I meant, code is great. 
However there's something I forgot... 
An <h1> can be sometimes placed before the <a> list, and should not be counted as an element. 
Any idea how to proceed ?